# Переход между страницами

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток! Как реализовать переход между страницами, чтобы содержимое "уезжало" вверх, а новая страница соответственно "выезжала" сверху?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пара плагинов, может пригодятся:

- [Jquery.ascensor.js](http://kirkas.ch/ascensor/)
- [jQuery Scroll Path](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/)